# how to use nested Json field as elasticsearch doc in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

say the event is like this:

```
{
  "name": "xxx", 
  "data": {
    "a": xxx
  }
}
```

with logstash, how to just use inner `data` field as document source send to elasticsearch, like:

```
{
  "a": xxx
}
```

any response would be appreciated！

---

tried to use `json` filter

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "data"
  }
}
```

but seems like the event is already parsed as a json, the terminal just print this error message:

```
Error parsing json {:source=>"data", :raw=>{"a"=>xxx}, :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyHash cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyIO}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, found an answer works
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/move-subarrays-to-document-root/143876

just use `ruby` code to move nested fields to document root , and `remove` all other fields

```
  ruby {
    code => 'event.get("data").each { | k, v| event.set(k, v) }'
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "name", "data" ]
  }
```